# How to make a JLabel change once based on time

Tags: java, timer, jlabel

I've ben researching how to use swing timers for 2 days now and am trying to figure out how to change the image I have at the center of my JFrame. As of now my program runs properly, but the image does not change the way I want it to. This class was just used as a test so it might not have proper java syntax.

```
    package hauntedHouseAdventure;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

public class timertest {
    static JFrame sceneOne = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(
            "/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/dark-forest-night-image.jpg");
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    sceneOne.add(panel);
    sceneOne.setResizable(false);
    imageLabel.setVisible(true);
    sceneOne.pack();

    JButton leave=new JButton("Leave");
    JButton stay= new JButton ("Stay");
    leave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            sceneOne.setVisible(false);
        }
    });      
    stay.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
           sceneOne.setVisible(false);
        }
    });      

    panel.add(leave, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.add(stay, BorderLayout.WEST);


    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test");

    label1.setText("<html><font color='red'> It was approximately 11:30 pm. The night sky was black not a single star piercing through the darkness"
            + "except the thick and powerful moonlight."
            + "<br>"
            + "You are alone leaving a costume party at a friend's place."
            + "It was rather boring and you decided to leave early."
            + "A stutter is heard and your"
            + "<br>"
            + "car begins to shake"
            + "Your headlights and car lights crack. The engine is left dead silent."
            + "You are left in a total silence"
            + "and baked in merely the moonlight."
            + "<br>"
            + "There is a mere second of silence till a harsh chill ripes through the"
            + "car like a bullet through paper. You are left dumbfounded. What do you do?</font><html>");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    label1.setVisible(true);
    label1.setOpaque(false);

  panel.add(label1); 

  final ActionListener updater = new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

          ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(
                  "/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/image-slider-5.jpg");
          JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
          panel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
          sceneOne.add(panel);

          }
  };



  Timer timer = new Timer(1000, updater);

  timer.start();





  sceneOne.setSize(2000,1000);
    sceneOne.setTitle("The Car");
    sceneOne.setVisible(true);
    sceneOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    sceneOne.setLocation(250, 200);
}
```

}

Comment: You are still not following Java naming conventions. `Variable names should not start with an upper case character`. You have had two weeks to fix the code since your last reminder on this subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23556317/131872. `This class was just used as a test so it might not have proper java syntax` - there is absolutely no reason to not follow the standards even for a test class. Namining conventions should be natural and the more you use them the more they will be natural. `If you want us to read your code then follow the conventions, its that simple.`

Comment: camickr, I understand your frustration, however I was in a predicament. I have actually taken the naming advice from the last program. However I could not use that as the eclipse on my main computer broke down. I did have the older version and copy and pasted it. Using a timed computer, I did not wish to go through the entire program fixing it.  I have in fact reinstalled eclipse and my JRE and will fix the syntax of this question promptly. My apologize and the advice was headed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems in your code.

1. You are adding the new image to your panel, but not removing the old image.
2. You are not telling to your frame that your components changed and he needs to redraw.

I think the best way to do this, is just changing the icon of your imageLabel. Like this:

```
final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
......
final ActionListener updater = new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/image-slider-5.jpg");
      imageLabel.setIcon(image);
      imageLabel.updateUI(); //Tell to your frame he needs to redraw the image
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look in detail but to change the image on the label then you don't need to create a new control, you just need to change the image on the existing one.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(
              "/Users/computerscience2/Desktop/image-slider-5.jpg");
      imageLabel.setIcon(image);

  }
```

You will also need to make imageLabel either a member variable or final so that the `actionPerformed` method can see it.